# Generating .dll using CMake

Tags: c, windows, dll, cmake

I have the following C files in windows XP.
optBladWriter.c
optWriteNlpEmpsFile.c
I would like to generate DLL for this code.
I used the command add_library .
My make file has the following :

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED ( VERSION 2.6)
add_library (optFmg optBladWriter.c optWriteNlpEmpsFile.c)
```

after running CMake using command prompt Project.sln is created. I imported it to the visual studio and built it. I got the optFmg.lib file. But I want the optFmg.dll file.

Can you help me in generating the dll file using cmake in the above case. Is there any particular command similar to add_library.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

[As documented](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake2.6docs.html#command:add_library), the default type of library is determined by the `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` variable. You can explicitly request a shared library with:

```
add_library(yourlib SHARED file.c ...)
```

Comment: +1 for adding a link to the list of command for CMake.  It's a great resource, because they're all on one HTML page and you can just search the web-page for what your looking for.  :-)

Comment: This also makes all dependencies built as `.dll`. Is there a way to produce `.dll` only for `file.c` itself?